# MySQL SELECT-queries not parallelized

Tags: mysql

I have a test-database (MySQL 8.1.0) with the following (InnoDB) scheme and loaded ~300,000 entries from that [dump-file](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db/blob/master/load_employees.dump)
Its around 15 MB of data.

If I execute the query "SELECT * FROM employees;", it takes around 140 ms on my test-machine (with 8 cores).
But when I execute the query 8 times in parallel (PHP-code below), it takes around 820 ms.
Why does it take so long?
My expectation was, that it should finish in around 200 ms as 8 cores could read the 8 requests in parallel.
Data comes from Cache (as there is no disk-IO from mysql-process during the queries).
As the last queries take over 500 ms, they are also writen to the slow-queries-log (long_query_time=0.5). innodb_buffer_pool_size is also way bigger (1G) than the DB (~20MB). The system has enough free RAM (so no swaping).

I can fully reproduce it on a Windows-Server (its even slower there...).

This is the PHP-code to execute the queries in parallel (I have also tested it with parallel requests from bash):

```
    $connections = [];
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++)
    {
        $connections[] = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', '...', '...', '...');
    }
    
    $start = microtime(true);
    
    foreach ($connections as $tmpConnection)
    {
        $tmpConnection->query('SELECT * FROM employees;', MYSQLI_ASYNC);
    }
    
    foreach ($connections as $tmpConnection)
    {
        $tmpConnection->reap_async_query();
    }
    
    $end = microtime(true);
    
    echo round($end - $start, 2) . "\n";
```

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,
    birth_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
    first_name  VARCHAR(14)     NOT NULL,
    last_name   VARCHAR(16)     NOT NULL,
    gender      ENUM ('M','F')  NOT NULL,    
    hire_date   DATE            NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no)
);
```

So my question is, why these queries are not processed in parallel - or does mysql not support this?

Comment: 'or does mysql not support this' - https://www.percona.com/blog/mysql-8-0-14-a-road-to-parallel-query-execution-is-wide-open/ from 2019 but I don't think things have moved on.

Comment: @P.Salmon, That blog is about progress to make a single query multi-threaded, which is a nascent feature and limited in its application. The OP is asking about running multiple queries concurrently on different connections. Each query is single-threaded, but MySQL should allow them to run in separate sessions in parallel. In fact, it is working, as evidence by the fact that the OP measures 820ms for 8 queries that each would take 140ms on their own. But there seems to be some high overhead to the concurrency.

Comment: Mac, Consider using -  $tmpConnection->query('SELECT * FROM employees;SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;', MYSQLI_ASYNC); - for your testing and analyze results, please.

Comment: The 'SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;' helped a lot.
It shows that execution of the commands is relly fast. But the transfer to the client (in this case the php-script) is the bottleneck.
Tried to save the result in shared-memory, but serialization and deserialization are the bottleneck then.

Comment: I ended up caching the result in shared memory.
Instead of using serialize() and unserialize() functions I am using the functions igbinary_serialize() and igbinary_unserialize() as they are faster and produce smaller output.